# Can I access resource path in Ballerina program?

Tags: ballerina

I'm looking to access the path of the resource dynamically inside 'getStudentById' resource. For e.g. if the service is called 'http://localhost:9090/studentfinder/student/0989898'. I want the '/student/0989898' part.

```
 @http:ResourceConfig {
        methods: ["GET"],
        path: "/student/{studentId}"
    }
    getStudentById(endpoint client, http:Request req, string studentId) {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw path from request object as follows:

```
req.rawPath
```

This should give the value you are looking for.

https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http/objects/Request.html